# Javascript Redirect in php if else statement

Tags: javascript, php

I have the below javascript function:

```
 function pageRedirect() {
     window.location.replace("ProdTypes.php");
 }
 setTimeout("pageRedirect()", 3000);
```

in a PHP if else statement (see below):

```
if($ptRowCount > 0) :
            if ($ptQTYRowCount > 0):
                $errors[]='Cannot delete or Archive product which has a Product Quantity > 0!!! Refreshing Page in 3 seconds...';
                ?>
                <script>
                    pageRedirect();
               </script>
                <?php 
                elseif($ptQTYRowCount == 0):
                $sql = "UPDATE producttype SET ProdTypeArchive='1' WHERE ProductTypeID = '$delete_id'";
                $_SESSION['success_flash']='Product Type was Archived succesfully';
            endif;
        else:
             $sql = "DELETE FROM producttype WHERE ProductTypeID = '$delete_id'";
             $_SESSION['success_flash']='Product Type was deleted succesfully';
        endif;
```

I require that the javascript counter only comes into action in the if statement where `if ($ptQTYRowCount > 0):`

At the moment it is realoading the page even when the if statement is not triggerred.

Anyone can help please?

P.S. I do not want to use Header for redirection. WHen I use headers I have the below error:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\aresV2\admin\includes\navigation.php:48) in C:\xampp\htdocs\aresV2\admin\ProdTypes.php on line 51

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear from your question, but if you include the entire block of code in your page (the function + setTimeout statement), this causes the page to always reload after 3 seconds.

The solution would be to remove the setTimeout line, and in your if statement replace

```
?>
<script>
    pageRedirect();
</script>
<?php
```

with

```
?>
<script>
    setTimeout("pageRedirect", 3000);
</script>
<?php
```

As for the error you get when trying to redirect using headers, this has been [answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php) here on SO

Comment: Yes that fixed the problem, exactly what I required. Thanks brain99